# Features components spontaneously reverting

Tags: 6, entities, features

On a multisite, we're using Features + UUID Features to manage a large quantity of default node and menu content.  Users can easily spawn a new multisite instance; the installation profile enables a set of Feature modules which create nodes and menu items.

Some of our users have reported that site content, which has been intentionally overridden by local site users, is spontaneously reverting to the version of content stored in the Feature.

What might be causing this?  What can we do to prevent it?

Comment: Is there a Feature that's conflicting with other Features, causing them to revert? I have had that issue with content type Features that the same fields with different values to other content type Features.

Comment: Hmm, nothing was showing on the Features status page as being in conflict or Needing Review, just Overridden.  I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on my test site, so I suspect it may have been user error (a content editor mistakenly reverted a Feature).

Comment: I had several content types all using the same field. When the field title was changed in one, it showed the others as overridden. If I reverted those, it showed the new one as overridden. I had to pick one way, stick with it, and `drush fu` the others.